# Mediamonkey ratings imported into Rhythmbox/Banshee/Quod Libet

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, mp3-tag, quodlibet

I recently made a complete shift from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. Everything went smoothly until I scanned my music files in some of the Ubuntu players...

All of my ratings added in Windows, using Mediamonkey, were out-of-five-stars (some with a half-star precision) - but when imported into RhythmBox, Banshee and Quod Libet, they all changed to a out-of-four-stars rating, with no five-star songs and no indication of how the old ratings were mapped into the new system.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Even getting to know which way the ratings were mapped from 5-star system (with a half-star increment) to a 4-star basis will be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer for Quod Libet, but like many others, this uses a decimal 0.0 - 1.0 rating system. In the user interface this appears as "stars" ([now any symbol](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=892) actually). The original value is rounded to the nearest number of stars configured (4 by default), i.e 0.5 = 2 stars. You can even search by ratings, e.g. `#(rating>=0.8)`

Note that this number of stars is itself configurable, so you see your 10 (5 and 5 halves) distinct ratings (See [Can I show more than 0 to 4 notes when rating songs?](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_show_more_than_0_to_4_notes_when_rating_songs?)). I'm not sure how MM stores them though (I seem to remember QL does understand them though). If you're seeing roughly the correct ratings already, it should work at the higher accuracy too.

Note there's some [discussion about potential improvements](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/detail?id=972) to the interface and configurability for all this.